# Excel Functions the looks up the text from one cell to see if it is with texts of other cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I invoice numbers that I am looking to see if there is a variation of the invoice number in another column.

Example

| Invoice # | Other Invoice # |
| --- | --- |
| SECR22-12345 | CREDIT SECR22-12345 |
|  | SECR11-12345-1545 |
|  | SECR66-12345AB |

I tried using the functions `ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,B2))`, which works for a one to one search. My issue is I am trying to compare and search against a whole column.

When I try using `ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,B2:B1000))`, it then returns `false`.

Overall, I have about 500 different invoice numbers that I am trying to find is there is any variation of that invoice number in Column B that has about 650 invoice numbers.

PS, this formula will eventually be part of a larger formula. So I cannot do anything special like using CTRL/Shift/Enter for an array. The larger formula is an Index/Match formula and I am trying to figure this part out for one the match criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Use wildcards in the MATCH:

```
=IF(A2<>"",INDEX(B:B,MATCH("*"&A2&"*",B:B,0)),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(FIND($A$2,B2)>0,B2),"")
```

[image]